# Recover Ubuntu on a dual boot after changing boot order

Tags: ubuntu, windows, dual-boot

I recently had Ubuntu and Windows as a dual boot. Ubuntu was first in the boot order then Windows. After changing the boot order in the HP BIOS to boot Windows first then Ubuntu, I can no longer boot into the Ubuntu partition. It is not even available in the boot menu. In windows Disk Management, I can see the Ubuntu partition (Healthy), however the Free Space equals the Capacity, so I also wonder whether it was erased.

My question is can I and how can I recover the Ubuntu partition? Many thanks!

Comment: Is it really BIOS or rather UEFI? Partition would mean one hard drive but then BIOS would have one option to select as boot device only.  Please specify what you mean by "boot menu".

Comment: It is UEFI. I only have one physical drive which I partitioned in two. By boot menu I mean the section in the UEFI where I can select which OS to boot into. Does a tool like Boot-repair-Disk sound like a tool to find a solution to recover the Ubuntu partition? Thanks

Comment: It is odd that it disappeared completely. First of all check if some Windows update reset the UEFI to use Secure Boot. If it still does not appear as option, yes, BootRepair is your way to go. Since you mention running Ubuntu you best just use an Ubuntu installation medium for this - it has boot repair available in the live version.

Comment: Boot-Repair will not fix missing partition, if that is issue.  Its main fix is a reinstall of grub. Lets see details, use ppa version with your live installer (2nd option) or any working install,  not Boot-Repair ISO:
Please copy & paste the pastebin link to the Boot-info summary report ( do not post report), do not run the auto fix till reviewed.
 https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair Be sure to boot in same mode UEFI or BIOS as your installs.

Comment: @oldfred AFAIK `grub`-repairs nowadays also handle EFI-fixes. Especially on very end-user-focused distros like Ubuntu.

Comment: Thanks guys. I managed to recover it with BootRepair. It found the drive easily and made it first in the boot order. I then changed the boot order to how I wanted it and it then stuck.